# How to get jQuery to work with Underscore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have an underscore template within that template I have this

```
<input type='checkbox' name='contacted_by_ae' class='contactedbyae'>
```

I am now trying to detect change so when a user clicks it. It will then post

```
$('.contactedbyae').change(function() {
    $.post( "/contactedbyae", function( data ) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

The above jQuery is not working though. I put it within my .html file and my actual underscore template file I can't get either to work. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Please add more information about the specific errors you're receiving

Comment: I get no error it just does nothing. If I take the code and put it in the console it works but not in the .html or underscore file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like there is no `.contactedbyae` element on the page, since template is not yet rendered at the time when event handler is being registered. In this case event delegation will help:

```
$('body').on('change', '.contactedbyae', function() {
    $.post( "/contactedbyae", function( data ) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Instead of `body` it's better to use a container selector rendered template HTML is appended to.

Comment: Couldn't he just wrap his event handler in the document.ready block?

Comment: @Stan, not if the template is re-rendered multiple times. The events might be bound the first time but subsequent rendering would clear the event handlers. Event delegation is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not appended the "compiled" template before youbset the event listener. You can use the [delegate method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of the `change` one to bind your callback...

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant.